# How to revert to default gravatar

Tags: support

I had stuck with my original/default gravatar thinking I may put my face up if I ever hit 10k as that seems to be the done thing round here.

Anyway I thought I would change it when everyone did the anti SOPA/PIPA thing but I couldn't suss out how to revert to the original so it's stuck ever since.

Am I being a retard or can it not be reverted?

Comment: You're not retarded, at least not for this reason. I also struggled to find out how to change my avatar, as it's anything but obvious.

Answer (score 5):

You need to go to [Gravitar](https://en.gravatar.com/) and log in.

Go to Account -> Manage My Gravitars.

Amongst other things you'll see something like this

[image: Gravitar Demo]

Click on the `Don't use this image` link and confirm.

You'll get something like

[image: Default Gravitar]

Now your Gravitar will revert to it's original [identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon). It's not instantaneous and may take up to 10 minutes or so.